# R: sparse.model.matrix(), new variable for each level

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, xgboost

Suppose I have a factor variable `type` with three levels: `1`, `2`, `3` and a dependent variable, `y` in a data frame, `df`.

If I do:

```
sparse.model.matrix(y ~ ., data = df)
```

The result is two variables for `type`: `type2` and `type3`. How do I get a new variable for each level of the original variable?

Answer (score 0):

This has probably been asked before but:

```
Matrix::sparse.model.matrix(y ~ .-1 , data = df)
```

You may also want to try `Matrix::fac2sparse(df$x)`